# How do I distribute $5\frac{-y+7}{2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is part of the problem $12 + 5\dfrac{-y+7}2 = 3y$. I feel that my issue with finding a correct answer is that I am not distributing correctly.

My first instinct was to multiply $-y$ and $7$ by $5$, because I believed that $\dfrac{-y+7}2 = \dfrac{-y}2 + \dfrac72$. Using that logic I came to an answer of $\dfrac{59}{11}$, but with the graphing system the web app uses the result can only be a multiple of $\dfrac 12$. A basic question I know, but I have had very little education and am trying hard to learn.

Comment: Should there be an x in it somewhere?

Comment: 5((-y+7/2) is a substitution for 5x. The subject is systems of equations and in this system x = (-y+7)/2.

Comment: The word is 'rearranging' not 'distributing'!

Comment: @mynameisnotsure, pls share what equation you fed to the graphing tool.

Comment: I didn't feed anything into a graphic tool. I am meant to do the graphing manually as part of the exercise after solving the problem for y algebraically. I'm sorry if anything I'm saying is not clear.

Comment: @mistermarko I could be doing this wrong. That 5 is supposed to be the coefficient to a variable that I'm substituting an equation for. From the lessons, I was under the impression that that was proper.

Comment: @mistermarko "Distributing" is correct for applying the distributive law.

Comment: It might help if you would post the original equations which you are trying to solve - it looks to me as though there are other things you could have done to make life easier for you. And that might also help us to see what the graphical solution is about.

Comment: I needed to solve for y using the system:
12 + 5x = 3y
x=\frac{-y+7}{2}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Multiply both sides of the original equation by $2$.

Comment: If I were to do this, would I multiply the constant, the coefficient, and the substitute by 2? Pardon if I am not clear, I am trying to use what I perceive to be common semantics.

Comment: You should multiply each term by two. In your case $[12]$ is a term and $[5\frac{-y+7}{2}]$ is a term.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to solve the following for $y$ 
$$12+5\times\frac{-y+7}{2}=3y, $$
then you are right with
$$12+5\times \left(-\frac y2+\frac 72\right)=3y$$
$$\iff 12-\frac{5\cdot y}{2}+\frac{5\cdot 7}{2}=3y.$$
Then, the answer is $y=59/11$, which is what you mentioned.